# TypeError: undefined is not a function when using highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I am using highchart to visualize some information on my mobile app. It is created using cordova, Jquery Mobile and AngularJS. When i run the app the chart is not displayed and i get the following error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.Ya.init (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox<div id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="ng-isolate-scope">S/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/highcharts.js:190:496)
at Object.Ya (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/highcharts.js:15:312)
at link.initChart (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/highcharts-ng.js:228:105)
at link (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/highcharts-ng.js:238:9)
at file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:67:494
at Fc (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:68:47)
at K (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:57:259)
at g (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:49:491)
at g (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:50:4)
at K (file:///D:/My%20Workspace/FireFox%OS/BMITracker_JQM/www/js/angular.min.js:57:204) VM1232 angular.min.js:98(anonymous function) VM1232 angular.min.js:98$get VM1232 angular.min.js:73Fc VM1232 angular.min.js:68K VM1232 angular.min.js:57g VM1232 angular.min.js:49g VM1232 angular.min.js:50K VM1232 angular.min.js:57g VM1232 angular.min.js:49g VM1232 angular.min.js:50(anonymous function) VM1232 angular.min.js:49(anonymous function) VM1232 angular.min.js:18$get.k.$eval VM1232 angular.min.js:120$get.k.$apply VM1232 angular.min.js:121(anonymous function) VM1232 angular.min.js:18e VM1232 angular.min.js:36d VM1232 angular.min.js:18hc VM1232 angular.min.js:18xd VM1232 angular.min.js:17(anonymous function) VM1232 angular.min.js:239a VM1232 angular.min.js:159c
```

I can't figure out what is wrong and where the error is coming from. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressPage" data-role="page" data-theme="a" ng-controller="ProgressController">
    ....

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="chart-canvas"></highchart>
    </div>

    ....
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
.controller('ProgressController', function($scope) {

    $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },

        loading: false
    };
})
```

**CSS**

```
.chart-canvas {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;    
}
```

Comment: At the beginning try to get rid of angularjs / jquery mobile, then initialise charts. If it will work, add modules (angular / jquery mobile) step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by removing these lines from `highcharts-ng.js`

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports !== 'undefined' && module.exports === exports){
     module.exports = 'highcharts-ng';
}
```

you can find it at the top of the file.

and Don't forget to include `jQuery`